# Actionscript regular expression for repeating characters

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I want to implement a regular expression check for a string with a character which repeats itself more than twice.
I am using ActionScript 3.

i.e.:

```
koby = true
kobyy = true
kobyyy = false
```

I tried using

```
/((\w)\2?(?!\2))+/
```

but it does not seem to work (using `RegExp.test()`)

Comment: @stema Right, I didn't notice the outer parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to invalidate the complete string, when there is a character repeated 3 times, you can use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
^(?!.*(\w)\1{2}).*
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?37m4j).

The group starting with `(?!` is a [negated lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). That means the whole regex (`.*` to match the complete string) will fail, when there is a word character that is repeated 3 times in the string.

`^` is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the start of the string.

```
^         # match the start of the string
(?!.*     # fail when there is anywhere in the string
    (\w)  # a word character
    \1{2} # that is repeated two times
)
.*        # match the string
```

Answer (score 1):

I also tried this one:

```
var regExp:RegExp = new RegExp('(\\w)\\1{2}');
trace(!regExp.test('koby'));
trace(!regExp.test('kobyy'));
trace(!regExp.test('kobyyy'));
```